# How to merge multiple list into a single dataframe, replacing common values with 1 - Python

Tags: python, list, dataframe, merge

I have multiple lists on python:

a = ["house","garden", "living room", "dog","cat"]

b= ["cat","dog", "chicken"]

c=["house", "garden","bathroom"]

I'd like to create the following dataframe:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| house | 0 | 1 |
| garden | 0 | 1 |
| living room | 0 | 0 |
| dog | 1 | 0 |
| cat | 1 | 0 |

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Create a single-column frame from `a`, then generate the remaining columns based on membership of `a`:

```
import pandas as pd

a = ["house","garden", "living room", "dog", "cat"]
b = ["cat","dog", "chicken"]
c = ["house", "garden", "bathroom"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=a, columns=['a'])
df['b'] = [int(s in b) for s in a]
df['c'] = [int(s in c) for s in a]

print(df)
```

Which gives an output of:

```
             a  b  c
0        house  0  1
1       garden  0  1
2  living room  0  0
3          dog  1  0
4          cat  1  0
```